# ¿Como puedo enviar un archivo a PHP por Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

me encuentro en la situación de: ¿como puedo enviar variables por POST y 1 FILES a traves de AJAX?.

y bueno utilizo AJAX solo para no refrescar la página.
dejo aquí el script con el que estoy intentando y el formulario.
Estaré atento a comentarios.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnUploadFileA").click(function() {
    var url = "process/A_GlobalFile.php";
    if (document.getElementById("fileA").files.length == 0) {
      alert("Seleccione un Archivo.");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#formUploadFileA").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
          resetAsignFiles();
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("??");
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formUploadFileA" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="text-align: center;width: 100%;">
      <span class="text-secondary"><b>Subir Archivo</b></span></h6>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="text-dark">Subir Instrumento</label>
      <br>
      <input name="fileA" id="fileA" class="text-dark" type="file" required="" />
      <input type="text" name="UnidadU" value="1" hidden="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="background-color: #6c757d;" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnUploadFileA" name="btnDelPost" style="background-color: #1ba7ff;" class="btn btn-primary">Subir Archivo</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnUploadFileA").click(function () {
        var url = "process/A_GlobalFile.php";
        var form = $('#formUploadFileA')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(data);
                resetAsignFiles();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("??");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yo lo hago asi, y posteriormente refresco la pagina en mi caso refresco la tabla.

```html
var save_data = function(table){
 $("#contactForm #contact_submit").on("click", function(e){

   e.preventDefault();
   var packetData = new FormData();
   packetData.append("name", $("#contactForm #name").val());

   $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: "./save",
    contentType: false,
    data: packetData,
    processData: false,
    cache: false
   }).done(function( info ){
    var json_info = JSON.parse(info);
    if (json_info.resp == "1"){
     var txt = "Datos Insertados / Actualizados";
    }else{
     var txt = "Error al Insertar / Actualizar";
    }
    view_msg(json_info,txt);
      table.ajax.reload();
     })
   
 });
}
```