# Consulta de AJAX y JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

compañeros. Gracias por ingresar a mi post.

Mi problema es que tengo un formulario, con diferentes tipos (text, number y files). El problema, es que el formulario se me envía perfectamente con esta línea de código:

```
var data=$("#formulario").serialize();
```

El problema, es que no me toma la imagen. Sé que este código no me funciona, pero he intentado con códigos de internet, pero no ha funcionado.

Este es el formulario:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <input type="number" name="cod_prod">
    <input type="text" name="nombre_prod">
    <input type="file" name="referencia_prod">
    <button id="subir">Subir.</button>
</form>
```

Este es mi código AJAX:

```
$("#subir").click(function(event) {
            /*Con esto evitamos que se recargue la página.*/
            event.preventDefault();
            var data=$("#formulario").serialize();
            $.ajax({                        
                method:"POST",                 
                url:"subir_fichas.php",
                data:data,
                success: function(data){
                    obtener_datos();     
                }
            });
        })
```

Sólo necesito que me tome todos los datos y la imagen para subirla a MySql.

Comment: hice una pregunta similar hace unos días... [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234862/como-puedo-enviar-un-archivo-a-php-por-ajax)

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo que postees el código de subir_fichas.php y de obtener_datos() para poder obtener una respuesta que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

el primer punto importante es que se debe indicar al formulario que debe manejar archivos:

`<form id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

y luego en jquery es necesario hacer uso de FormData, que es la forma en la que ajax envia archivos:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subir").click(function () {
        var url = "subir_fichas.php";
        var form = $('#formulario')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data){
                // cosas por hacer si exito
            },
            error: function() {
                //cosas por hacer si error
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Ya lo intenté, pero al hacer Alert(formData) me muestra el recuadro: [object FormData]

Comment: eso se debe a que que se envia un objeto, lo creas al hacer `var formData = new FormData(form);` no entiendo para que quieres hacer un alert, de cualquier modo ahora ese objeto tiene  contenido al formulario incluyendo ek archivo

Comment: Sí, ya pude. Muchas gracias a todos los que aportaron. Ahora, el problema es que al hacer click en enviar, me envía a la página principal.

Comment: eso es simple agrega ` event.preventDefault();` como lo tenias al principio